# Mac doesn't recognize Android 2.1 phone

Tags: android

I'm trying to set up my old Android phone for testing my apps. The phone is still on 2.1 (Samsung Captivate) and is inactive. I can't get my Macbook Pro on OS X (10.8.2) to recognize the phone. I have the box checked for USB debugging in settings, but when I plug the USB cable in, nothing happens. If I go to the adb directory and type ./adb devices, I show no devices attached.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all Install device drivers for your phone if you have not installed it.
if you already did it and still not recognizing then try rebooting the device and Mac both.may b it will work.

Comment: On Mac we don't have such thing as "device drivers", it should "just work".

Comment: I found in the documentation exactly what harism said. I did try installing Kies for Mac, but that didn't help either.